Can I run 2 SER cables through same hole?
Is this ok? I didn't see anything in NEC about it, but still question it.
The rear cable is the main service line coming from the meter, the other is 2-2-2-4 AL cable I'm running for a new subpanel.
The hole was created by the builders through the bottom plate, nicks the rim joist, and goes into the crawl space. Because of a floor joist, and other obstructions in the crawl space behind the rim joist, my only other option is to open up the bay to the right of the panel, create a similar hole, run the cable into there, through the stud and into the side of the panel. This would cut out a lot of headache if I can just use the same hole.


2-2-2-4 is only 90 amp wire unless it is serving the entire load of a dwelling e.g. an ADU/in-law apartment.  The issue at hand is you are running feeder (past the main breaker) alongside service wire (before the main breaker).  Damage to those cables could energize the 2-2-2-4 at up to 10,000 amps with no breaker protection at all.
